# Rails / Font awesome - icon sizing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

i am trying to make a font awesome icon go `icon-2x` in a rails app but it cant find the class it seems. i am using the [font awesome gem](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) i am using html.erb and scss with rails 3.2.13 and ruby 2.0.0-p0. i have `@import 'font-awesome';` in my scss. and in my html have called

```
<i class="icon-reorder icon-large"></i>
```

Which works fine. but changing the size to `icon-2x` sets it back to the default small size.
I then saw that there are some cool helpers that he set up some helpers like the following

```
fa_icon "reorder 4x muted", class: "pull-left"
```

So i tried

```
<% fa_icon "reorder 4x muted", class: "pull-left" %>
```

To which i get the following error.

```
undefined method `fa_icon' for #<#<Class:0x007ff5569d7b70>:0x007ff556b7d268>
```

Anyone come up with something similar. do i have to include the helper anywhere?? i have called the gem outside the asset group within my gemfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `<% ... %>` will only execute the ruby code within the scriplets.  I think you want to output the returned value using `<%= ... %>`.  Try:

```
<%= fa_icon "reorder 4x muted", class: "pull-left" %>
```

**Update:**

```
undefined method `fa_icon' for #<#<Class:0x007ff5569d7b70>:0x007ff556b7d268>
```

This error does not seem to be thrown on `font-awesome-rails-3.2.1.3`, tested in both Rails 4.0 and 3.2.  OP, who had `font-awesome-rails-3.2.1.2` reported that upgrading to `font-awesome-rails-3.2.1.3` resolved this issue.

Comment: still get the same thing hey.

Comment: Gem installed fine, restarted the server?  What version is this gem and what version is your rails?

Comment: in my gemfile the gem is listed as follows `gem "font-awesome-rails"` -> Using font-awesome-rails (3.2.1.2) the rails version is 3.2.13. yeah i ran bundle and restarted the server a few times

Comment: Hmmm, I just tested that line and got `<i class="icon-reorder icon-4x icon-muted pull-left"></i>`.  The only difference between your and my test setup is I have `font-awesome-rails 3.2.1.3`

Comment: thats hectic. i just pulled again. i wonder why yours is a more recent version as well? are you also using ruby 2.0.0-p0

Comment: No ruby is: `1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553)`.  Try `bundle update font-awesome-rails`.  Tested in rails 4.0 and ruby 2.0 as well, get the same result.

Comment: sweet that worked i am now sitting on the same version of font-awesome-rails as you and i am not getting the error any more. but it seems as if the tag isnt rendering anything now. :(

Comment: cool its rendering the icon. but i still cant get it to resize ` <%= fa_icon "reorder large ", class: "pull-left" %>` works but ` <%= fa_icon "reorder 2x ", class: "pull-left" %>` wont hhaha

Comment: LOL, need some sleep I guess.  You're right.  I also couldn't render the icon, it appears that `muted` is the culprit here.  Remove `muted` option and give it a try.

Comment: `<%= fa_icon "reorder icon-2x " %>` and 
`<i class="icon-reorder icon-4x"></i>` are rendering as the same as the smallest size you get. its pretty baffling

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35403/discussion-between-vinodadhikary-and-thelegend)